# Se agotó el tiempo de espera de ejecución

Tags: c#, mvc

Estoy teniendo el siguiente error durante una transacción en C# ASP.NET MVC:

**Se agotó el tiempo de espera de ejecución. El período de tiempo de espera transcurrió antes de la finalización de la operación o el servidor no responde. The statement has been terminated.**

La verdad no sé dónde ni porqué se genera el error, les dejo la parte en donde la utilizo:

```
string cm = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdminEntities"].ToString().Split('"')[1];
for(int i = 0; i < modsCant.Length; i++)
{
   sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO EmpresasModulos(EmpresaId, ModuloId) VALUES(" + empresa.Id +  "," + modulos[i] + ")";
   
   using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(cm))
   {
       using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, sqlConnection))
       {
           sqlConnection.Open();

           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Revisa que tu servidor de base de datos no este colapsado, o que no colapse cuando haces este proceso. Si no tendrás que aumentar el tiempo de respuesta del servidor de la base de datos.

Comment: No se si puedo aportar mucho pero yo alguna consulta así complicada que la he echo con Sql en el código lo hacia con Transacciones para poder agilizar la carga

Comment: Yo lo haría en una sola instrucción con INSERT SELECT. es decir, usaría el for para formar la cadena SELECT con los valores EmpresaId y Modulo, al final harías un solo INSERT con SELECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que cambiaría en tu caso. Para empezar tu sentencia es vulnerable a [SQL Injection](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL), debes cambiarla y utilizar los [SqlParameter](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.0)s:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = ...)
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand =
       new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO EmpresasModulos(EmpresaId, ModuloId) VALUES(@EmpresaId, @Modulo)", sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@EmpresaId", empresa.Id);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Modulo", modulos[i]);
   
        sqlConnection.Open();
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Devuelve el número de registros afectados
    }
}
```

En segundo lugar, como comenta @ErickCastillo, para evitar múltiples operaciones, es mejor preparar una sola sentencia con todo lo que quieras hacer (recomiendo usar el [StringBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0)):

```
StringBuilder commandBuilder = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO EmpresasModulos(EmpresaId, ModuloId) VALUES ")
for (int i = 0; i < modsCant.Length; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
        commandBuilder.Append(", ");
    commandBuilder.Append("(@EmpresaId, @Modulo").Append(i).Append(")");
}
commandBuilder.Append(';');
/*
 * Resultado esperado:
 * INSERT INTO EmpresasModulos(EmpresaId, ModuloId) VALUES 
 * (@EmpresaId, @Modulo0), (@EmpresaId, @Modulo1), ...;
 */

// ... en el comando:
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(commandBuilder.ToString(), sqlConnection)
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@EmpresaId", empresa.Id);
        for (int i = 0; i < modsCant.Length; i++)
        {
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add($"@Modulo{i}", modulos[i]);
        }
        ...
    }
```

En tercer lugar, para que la ejecución en la base de datos no termine en poco tiempo, aprovechando el código anterior solo debes especificar un *timeout* suficientemente amplio (por supuesto, antes del `Execute`), o dejarlo en `0` para no tener límite de tiempo:

```
sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

### Trabajando con SQL Server

En tercer lugar, si estás utilizando SQL Server puedes aprovechar los [procedimientos almacenados](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15) para dejar que sea el propio motor de la BD el que se encargue de hacer toda esa tarea. Esto en particular te lo recomiendo por si tu sistema crece.

```sql
-- Primero definir una tabla que sirva para enviar toda la colección de datos de una sola vez
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[CustomTable_EmpresaModulo] AS TABLE(
    [EmpresaId] INT, -- O el tipo de dato que corresponda
    [ModuloId] INT
)
GO

-- Crear el procedimiento que reciba los datos
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CSP_InsertEmpresaModulo]
    @Data [CustomTable_EmpresaModulo] READONLY -- El READONLY es importante con los parámetros tablas
AS
BEGIN
    -- Si no quieres que dé cuenta de la cantidad de registros afectados,
    -- si quieres que sí entregue esa información, quita la siguiente línea:
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [EmpresasModulos]([EmpresaId], [ModuloId])
        SELECT [EmpresaId], [ModuloId]
          FROM @Data;
END
```

Teniendo esto ya armado, entonces en *C#* cambiamos la estructura, así:

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("EmpresaId", typeof(int)); // Deben coincidir con los tipos en SQL
dt.Columns.Add("ModuloId", typeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < modsCant.Length; i++)
{
    DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
    r["EmpresaId"] = empresa.Id;
    r["ModuloId"] = modulos[i];
    dt.Rows.Add(r);
}
dt.AcceptChanges(); // Confirma los cambios en la DataTable

using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = ...)
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand =
       new SqlCommand("EXEC [dbo].[CSP_InsertEmpresaModulo]", sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
        var param = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@Data",
            Value = dt,
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured
        };
        // Alternativa más simple:
        // var param = new SqlParameter("@Data", dt);

        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

        sqlConnection.Open();
        int affected = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Lo del NOCOUNT
    }
}
```

La alternativa a todo esto es que te aventures con [Entity Framework](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/entity-framework-introduction-using-c-sharp-part-one/), pero sea cual sea el camino que elijas, yo te recomiendo que empieces a estructurar tus accesos a BD, a medida que tu sistema crezca deberás tener más cuidado.

Comment: Muchas gracias! voy a probar esto!!

Comment: Entity framework lo queria usar ya que me parecia un poco mas sencillo, pero al no tener una PK en la tabla me tira error.

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar ejecutar multiples insert dentro de un for, podrías hacerlo con INSERT SELECT de la siguiente manera:

```
 string cm = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdminEntities"].ToString().Split('"')[1];
            string cadenaValues = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < modsCant.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    cadenaValues = "(" + empresa.Id + ", " + modulos[i] + ") ";
                }
                else {
                    cadenaValues = cadenaValues + " , " + "(" + empresa.Id + ", " + modulos[i] + ")";
                }

            }

            if(cadenaValues !="") {  

                sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO EmpresasModulos(EmpresaId, ModuloId) VALUES " + cadenaValues;

                using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(cm))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, sqlConnection))
                    {
                        sqlConnection.Open();

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
```